Simple Discord bot written in Python, command_prefix error, (intents) error
I am working on a project. It looks like I am getting an error with the 'commands' module in python "includes'.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = "mytoken"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} succesfully logged in!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    
    if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi {message.author}')
    if message.content == 'bye':
        await message.channel.send(f'Goodbye {message.author}')

    await bot.process_commands(message)


# Start each command with the @bot.command decorater
@bot.command()
async def square(ctx, arg): # The name of the function is the name of the command
    print(arg) # this is the text that follows the command
    await ctx.send(int(arg) ** 2) # ctx.send sends text in chat

@bot.command()
async def scrabblepoints(ctx, arg):
    # Key for point values of each letter
    score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
         "x": 8, "z": 10}
    points = 0
    # Sum the points for each letter
    for c in arg:
        points += score[c]
    await ctx.send(points)


bot.run(TOKEN)

debug output:
% python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamiemorrissey/Downloads/discord_bot/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

How can I fix this?

You might want revoke that security token right now.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") expects a keyword argument, intents.

Try replacing:
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

with:
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default())

This should fix the problem of not having intents.
For more information, check the discord.py documentation.

nice, got the certificate to work and got the bot logged in. Thanks. Now onto my next project!
